# Create a rolling index of pairs over groups

Tags: r

I need to create (with R) a rolling index of pairs from a data set that includes groups. Consider the following data set:

```
times <- c(4,3,2)
V1 <- unlist(lapply(times, function(x) seq(1, x)))
df <- data.frame(group = rep(1:length(times), times = times), 
                 V1 = V1, 
                 rolling_index = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5))

df
  group V1 rolling_index
1     1  1             1
2     1  2             1
3     1  3             2
4     1  4             2
5     2  1             3
6     2  2             3
7     2  3             4
8     3  1             5
9     3  2             5
```

The data frame I have includes the variables group and V1. Within each group V1 designates a running index (that may or may not start at 1).

I want to create a new indexing variable that looks like rolling_index. This variable groups rows within the same group and consecutive V1 value, thus creating a new rolling index. This new index must be consecutive over groups. If there is an uneven amount of rows within a group (e.g. group 2), then the last, single row gets its own rolling index value.

Comment: your rolling index group tows with consecutive `V1` value. However this is not what you displayed in your `data.frame`, for example from line `6` to `7`.

Comment: this is not an error. Within group 2, I use the first two observations (row 5 and 6) for a new grouping (rolling_index = 3). Since I only have one observation left in this group, it gets its own rolling_index value (4)

Comment: Please show your desired output

Comment: I want to create a variable that looks like rolling_index

Comment: What is the pattern of this index? You want a new index per each two rows within each `group`?

Comment: I want to make a pairwise grouping of consecutive observations within each group, and give them a new index value that runs over all groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,  gr:=as.numeric(gl(.N, 2, .N)), group][, 
     rollindex:=cumsum(c(TRUE,abs(diff(gr))>0))][,gr:= NULL]
#    group V1 rolling_index rollindex
#1:     1  1             1         1
#2:     1  2             1         1
#3:     1  3             2         2
#4:     1  4             2         2
#5:     2  1             3         3
#6:     2  2             3         3
#7:     2  3             4         4
#8:     3  1             5         5
#9:     3  2             5         5
```

Or using `base R`

```
 indx1 <- !duplicated(df$group)
 indx2 <- with(df, ave(group, group, FUN=function(x)
                           gl(length(x), 2, length(x))))
 cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(indx2)>0)|indx1)
 #[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 5
```

#### Update

The above methods are based on the 'group' column.  Suppose you already have a sequence column ('V1') by group as showed in the example, creation of rolling index is easier

```
 cumsum(!!df$V1 %%2)
 #[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 5
```

As mentioned in the post, if the 'V1' column do not start at '1' for some groups, we can get the sequence from the 'group' and then do the `cumsum` as above

```
 cumsum(!!with(df, ave(seq_along(group), group, FUN=seq_along))%%2)
 #[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 5
```

Comment: so here is the better way with base R ;-)

Comment: @CathG  It was so simple but we didn't spot it earlier.

Answer (score 5):

There is probably a simpler way but you can do:

```
rep_each <- unlist(mapply(function(q,r) {c(rep(2, q),rep(1, r))}, 
                          q=table(df$group)%/%2,
                          r=table(df$group)%%2))

df$rolling_index <- inverse.rle(x=list(lengths=rep_each, values=seq(rep_each)))

df$rolling_index 
#[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 5
```